# What does "get him" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph and I found the expression "get him" is hard for me to understand. Can you help me. Thank!

> A woman will not become more interested in you because you are a very busy guy, especially when you have the opportunity to keep flirting with her but decide that something else is more important than she is. A male’s lack of charm will make him lose more women in the long run than his imaginary busy schedule will **get him**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, "get" has the meaning "gain" or "acquire."

Now, that said, while the idea of "getting a woman" has been used in English for a long time to refer to finding a romantic partner, nowadays this usage would be ill-advised, as it gestures towards objectification.